# How do I make sure inputting a number will get a random result as listed?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a scenario in a game I'm developing for a class. In the scenario, the player finds three rooms that randomize themselves, one of which has the key they need. However, whenever I test the code to see if it works, instead of placing the player in a room, the code "rewinds" to an earlier decision and goes from there.

I've tried repositioning the input, the random, and different functions to make this work as intended, but to no avail.
For example, I've tried placing input() before my while loop, and I've also tried defining other fuctions to act as a sort of pathway for my input().

```
def checkRoom():
    room = input()
    return room
    while room != '1' or room != '2' or room != '3':
        room1, room2, room3 = random.sample(range(1, 4), 3)
        if room == str(room1):
            print('You enter a room.')
            time.sleep(1)
            print('''The room looks like a replica of your dungeon room,
    but nothing else is unusual about the room. You leave the
    room.''')
            time.sleep(5)
            checkRoom()
        elif room == str(room2):
            print('You enter a room.')
            time.sleep(1)
            print('''The room appears, weirdly, as a leisure library. 
Every book in the library is a different novel; not a spell book
in sight. While you'd love to sit and enjoy a good book,
you want out of this castle as soon as possible. You leave
the room.''')
            time.sleep(6)
            checkRoom()
        elif room == str(room3):
            print('You enter a room.')
            time.sleep(1)
            print('''You see the room is completely empty, save for a 
single nightstand. You go over to it and open it, revealing a
generic-looking key. You take the key and walk over to
the door to the castle, placing the key in the keyhole
and turning it, eliciting a "Click!" from the door as
it opens to the outside.''')
            time.sleep(8)
            print('You escaped! Now to destroy the castle.')
            time.sleep(3)
            endgame()
```

What should happen is the player enters a room that randomizes, but eventually is the room the player needs to exit the castle. What actually happens is that the player is "rewinded" to earlier inputs and the code jumps back to those inputs and runs from there.

Comment: Right off the bat, `def checkRoom():
    room = input();
    return room` won't do anything useful. Why are you returning `room` right away? None of the rest of the code in the function can run.

Comment: Why does the function call itself? Why does it return before doing anything (and how can it have the behavior you describe if it does)? Why does it have a `while` loop on a condition that can't ever change?

Comment: Don't try to use a while loop and recursion at the same time. You will only confuse yourself. Think more clearly about your control flow, and think of a way to do it with only the loop.

Comment: Also, if the rooms are randomizing themselves, then why do you really care about comparing the user's input to anything? Just randomly choose one of the results for going into a room.